Does the behaviour at triple point violate the laws of thermodynamics?
Thermodynamics postulates that if we have an isolated collection of matter, then given enough time, it will reach a state of thermodynamic equilibrium, and so we will not observe any macroscopic changes anymore. This statement is often called the minus-first law of thermodynamics. It can be found in Wikipedia (it is in the subsection "Thermodynamic state of internal equilibrium of a system").
Based on our everyday experience, this a believable postulate. However, in several videos of water at triple point, we definitely see macroscopic changes, since parts of water change from solid to liquid to gas and vice-versa, and this happens all the time.
Why doesn't this behaviour contradict the minus-first law? I have thought of a simple explanation. Please let me know if it's correct and if not, please provide the correct one. It would help me a lot!
My proposed explanation: in the video, not enough time has passed for the system to reach thermodynamic equilibrium. If the experimenter had waited long enough, the following would happen: a certain fraction of water would evaporate and would be mixed with the air inside the vacuum chamber. The rest of water would be a mix of ice, liquid, and gas (the latter would be in the form of bubbles, in the interior of the water mass). However, contrary to the video, this picture would be fixed in time, for example a frozen part would not spontaneously melt, a bubble would not be spontaneously crush etc.

No, the Gibbs phase rule allows for 3 phases to coexist at a fixed temperature and pressure. It does not say that there will not be changes of solid to liquid or gas - in fact those changes are going on all the time in any equilibrium situation.

So, are you claiming that Wikipedia is wrong? I put here the precise quote from Wikipedia: "A collection of matter may be entirely isolated from its surroundings. If it has been left undisturbed for an indefinitely long time, classical thermodynamics postulates that it is in a state in which no changes occur within it, and there are no flows within it." Also, why the downvote?

No net change in macroscopic parameters. Even in a two-phase situation, say ice in water, atoms are continually leaving the solid for the liquid and the liquid for the solid. Equilibrium is when the two balance each other, just as in chemical reactions coming to equilibrium.

A macroscopic observable though can be the following: whether a fixed macroscopically large region is solid or liquid or gas.  Such an observable changes with time in the video.

@JonCuster how can phase changes go on in an isolated system when internal thermal equilibrium is attained. In the absence of internal temperature differences there can be no heat between, say, the liquid and solid phases of a mixture

@BobD - atoms are switching back and forth all the time in equilibrium. All motion does not stop all of a sudden. It is just that the rates of  A -> B and B -> A become equal. This is what detailed balance is all about.

@JonCuster you seem to imply that since the relative amounts are constant, then we have thermodynamic equilibrium. However, thermodynamic equilibrium is much more strict! From Wikipedia: “in thermodynamic equilibrium there is absence of macroscopic change”. Now if a macroscopically large part of water spontaneously transforms from solid to liquid, then we definitely have macroscopic change!

@JonCuster Right. Forgot we’re talking about energy transfer between phases at the individual molecular (microscopic) level as opposed to energy transfer at the collective (macroscopic) level (i.e. heat, requiring temperature difference).

The video is misleading in that it claims the system on display is in thermodynamic equilibrium. But there is boiling going on so the liquid is flowing in complicated way, so obviously, it isn't in thermodynamic equilibrium. It just has temperature and pressure close to triple point. The system is, at best, in dynamic phase equilibrium, where in time, macroscopic elements of water change their macrostate. Thermodynamic equilibrium requires there is no macroscopic process going on. It is almost unattainable, idealized state of things.

@JánLalinský thank you for answering! It seems that you agree with my explanation. Please confirm.

If the system was really isolated, then yes, we expect all macroscopic processes to stop. But in the video, the system is maintained dynamically, by a vacuum pump, and probably some freezer with thermostat. These devices produce vibrations and small changes of pressure and temperature, they can't maintain perfectly static environment.

OK! Thanks a lot!

I don't understand how this could be a homework question

@LPZ I agree and have voted to reopen.
